# Plugin for Google Apps "Short Links" service?

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I have a Google Apps–enabled WordPress site and a subdomain where [Google Short Links](http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=5143210+6352879591152674960) runs. I've been toying with the idea of shortening my own links, but I haven't been able to find a WordPress plugin that hooks into the Short Links API to automatically add new posts as they're published (and maybe old posts too).

Does a plugin exist to do this? Ideally it would also add a `<link rel="shortlink">` tag to each page, but I could extend it with code from other plugins to do that. It should store the shortlink somewhere in the database, of course, so other plugins can access the link for tasks like posting to Twitter, Facebook, and so forth.

Comment: I can't find any API documentation. Can you provide it?

Comment: It looks like there isn't any API documentation, at least not that I can find. There are bookmarklets available to automatically create shortlinks, but they work only if logged in to the domain authentication.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not wedded to Google Short Links, another open source solution to try is [YOURLS](http://yourls.org/) which has a WordPress plugin.

Comment: YOURLS is a great option, but I am trying to use Google's service. I'm trying to not burden my shared server with a lot of services, so I'm offloading as much of the work as I can. However, if I can't make Short Links happen as I want it to, I might end up going with YOURLS anyway. Thanks!